# Can I get docker images of latest version of FIWARE products?

Tags: docker, fiware, fiware-orion, dockerhub, fiware-cygnus

I could not find [Orion 3.3.0](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/tags) nor [Cygnus 2.14.0](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/cygnus-ngsi/tags) official docker images at the docker hub.

How can I pull them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the decision of Docker to [remove or limit automated builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) from various account types. It has made collating the images much more complicated. Previously the FIWARE Builds would trigger as clones of the contributory repositories. The problems caused by this issue have been recognized by the [Technical Steering Committee](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IQccH7LteMSxilQ7QImLaYsduikDyaoK83_hEI1-M0U/view) of FIWARE. At the moment builds are transitioning to a newer build mechanism - possibly using a duplicate or alternative image repositories as well.

In most cases, such as the case of Orion and Cygnus created by Telefónica, you will still be able find tagged build generated from the original source repository under their own Docker Hub account - e.g [`telefonicaiot/fiware-orion`](https://hub.docker.com/r/telefonicaiot/fiware-orion/tags) and [`telefonicaiot/fiware-cygnus`](https://hub.docker.com/r/telefonicaiot/fiware-cygnus). The FIWARE clones of these images (a `pull/push` of the same SHA1 hash) are built and tested  by the `fiwarebot` periodically - [`fiware/orion:3.3.0`](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/tags?page=1&name=3.3.0) is now available for example, but the mechanism to fully standardize and automate this procedure will need some bedding in.

Once the system is fully in place, it is likely that the FIWARE builds will still lag the builds made by the teams behind each generic enabler, but a standard release will occur in alignment with each of the full [FIWARE Releases](https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue/releases)